# mysql_fetch_array from 3 different databases in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a website where data is displayed from different databases. 
I made 3 simple databases (Application(app_id, app_name), Manager(manager_id, manager_name), Website(website_id, website_name))

Here is the code that I used to connect to the databases:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("Application", $con);

$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT a.app_id, a.app_name FROM Application a");


//connection with other db
$con2 = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con2)
  {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("Manager", $con2);

$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT b.manager_id, b.manager_name FROM Manager b");

//connection with other db
$con3 = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con3)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("Website", $con3);

$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT c.website_id, c.website_name FROM Website c");
```

then I echo it in a table:

```
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Application</th>
<th>Manager</th>
<th>Website</th>
</tr>";

while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) && ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) && ($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)))

  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['app_id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['app_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['manager_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row2['website_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
mysql_close($con2);
```

This is displaying the data in a table, but without a relation so I created this:

```
$resultcombo = mysql_query("SELECT a.app_id, a.app_name, b.manager_name, c.website_name FROM Application.Application a JOIN Manager.Manager b on a.app_id = b.manager_id JOIN Website.Website c ON a.app_id = c.website_id ");
```

The above query works in phpmyadmin and it displays the correct information linked to each other (ID 1 = Application x, Manager x, Website x)

But how do I make a connection to 3 different databases (maybe more in the future) to fill the table with the correct application linked to the manager and the website?

I have a feeling that the 3 connections I made are useless, because the table is filled incorrect. Maybe I have to make 1 mysql_connect to 3 different databases.

please note: I used 3x localhost for test purpose, but in future i would like to use databases with different urls!

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** `mysql_*` functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared, Parameterized Queries.

Comment: So, apart from using deprecated API, you're trying to establish a relation between data that's not even a part of the same database. I won't ask why, people tend to do incredibly stupid things, this isn't even as silly as it may sound - but, you do realize this is the wrong way to use a relational database? You're treating it as a big, distributed text file. Bottom line - while everything is possible, do you really want to complicate your life? Creating 3 tables in the same database and joining them to get the result should be way more than enough. Remember the K.I.S.S. principle.

Comment: It's not 3 tables in the same database..
There are 3 databases each database has a table with the same name as the database

Comment: In the end, this is your project and it's clear you're misusing software such as database. You can either accept opinion of other developer(s) who have been working with these systems for past 20 years or you can persist in doing what you think is right - the choice is yours and it's easy nowadays to confirm whether you've done something that makes sense. 3 databases containing a table with the same name, residing on different hosts - there has to be a purpose to this, and it comes out of solving a certain problem. If there's no problem or purpose, it's clear misuse of the db.

Answer (score 3):

With respect, you are confused about the difference between **database** and **table.** You said this query works.

```
SELECT a.app_id, a.app_name, 
       b.manager_name, c.website_name
  FROM Application a
  JOIN Manager b on a.app_id = b.manager_id
  JOIN Website c ON a.app_id = c.website_id
```

This is clear evidence that you have just one **database** with three **tables** in it. The tables are `Application`, `Manager`, and `Website`.

**EDIT** after the questioner clarified the question.

You have two possible situations here.

1. You have multiple databases residing in the same MySQL server.
2. You have multiple databases residing in different MySQL servers.

In the first case, it seems likely from your question that you have just one username/password combination that can access all three databases. So, just use one connection, and use queries like this.

```
SELECT a.app_id, a.app_name, 
       b.manager_name, c.website_name
  FROM Application.Application a
  JOIN Manager.Manager b on a.app_id = b.manager_id
  JOIN Manager.Website c ON a.app_id = c.website_id
```

You already know you can qualify table names with database names in queries *if they are on the same server* and *your connection username has access to them all*. So, program as if your tables are co-located.

If your databases are potentially on different MySQL servers, you are buying yourself a giant hairball. (That's a technical term.) You can...

1. Use a different connection for each MySQL server, read the data from each table separately into your php program, and join it using various php list-processing algorithms, or...
2. Build yourself a bunch of [federated MySQL servers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-create-server.html) that can access each others' data.

But you should refrain from designing your system that way unless you absolutely must do so.

Why might you have to do this?

- Maybe the tables are too vast to fit into a single server. That seems unlikely. They've have to have at least 10^10 rows each to be too large for one server. In that case, you probably already have a database administrator. Ask for help.
- Maybe you don't own the data, and you have to report from it in real time, without any delay to allow you first to upload it to your MySQL server.

If you use a multiple-server design for mission-critical production work, you are committing yourself to awful headaches for the entire production lifetime of your system. You may want to hire a database administrator to handle some of those headaches. Seriously. Avoid this.

Comment: Sorry I edited the code before pasting it here.  

    SELECT a.app_id, a.app_name, 
           b.manager_name, c.website_name
      FROM Application.Application a
      JOIN Manager.Manager b on a.app_id = b.manager_id
      JOIN Website.Website c ON a.app_id = c.website_id

I have 3 databases  (Application, Manager, Website) in each database i created a table with the same name

I edited the post!

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer!

One more question remains, how do I echo the data from the query into a table? Using $resultcombo = mysql_query(SELECT a.app_id, a.app_name, 
       b.manager_name, c.website_name
  FROM Application.Application a
  JOIN Manager.Manager b on a.app_id = b.manager_id
  JOIN Manager.Website c ON a.app_id = c.website_id"); and then while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultcombo)) doesn't work for me.